# Rotating an image using cImage

Tags: python

I'm trying to rotate an image in Python by 90 degrees using cImage (and only cImage) and here's what I've got so far.

```
def rotateImage90CW(imageFile):
    myWin = ImageWin("90D", 350, 630)
    oldIm = FileImage(imageFile)
    newIm = EmptyImage(350, 630)
    bigList = []
    for row in range(oldIm.getHeight()):
        bigList.append([]);
        for column in range(oldIm.getWidth()):
            x = oldIm.getPixel(column, row)
            bigList[row].append(x)
    bigList.reverse()
    for row in range(newIm.getHeight()):
        for column in range(newIm.getWidth()):
            newIm.setPixel(column, row, bigList[column][row])
    newIm.draw(myWin)
```

Unfortunately, it only gives me a fully black image when I load the function. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? :[ Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a `list` to store the pixel data (and on top of that `x = oldIm.getPixel(column, row)` instead of `(row, column)`)? Personally I would simply create a new image with width = old_height and height = old_width and then simply iterate in the proper order to populate it with the pixel data from the old image.

Comment: True, I shortened it and now it looks like this  
`def rotateImage90CW(imageFile):
    myWin = ImageWin("90D", 350, 630)
    oldIm = FileImage(imageFile)
    newIm = EmptyImage(350, 630)
    for row in range(oldIm.getHeight()):
        for column in range(oldIm.getWidth()):
            x = oldIm.getPixel(column, row)
            newIm.setPixel(row, column, x)
    newIm.draw(myWin) `
but it still gives a full black image

Comment: Btw whenever you have something as important as updated code it's a common practice to add an **EDIT** in your original post and simply put it there. Comments, as you can see yourself, are not meant for multi-line code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I used `map` and `zip` to basically transpose your list:

from cImage import ImageWin, FileImage, EmptyImage

```
def rotate90D(img):
  '''
  Rotate +90deg
  '''
  assert img != None, 'Image is empty!'
  map(list, zip(*img)) # transpose; this can be called multiple times to rotate to 0, 90, 180, 270

def rotate90D_(img):
  '''
  Rotate -90deg
  '''
  assert img != None, 'Image is empty!'
  img.reverse()
  map(list, zip(*img)) # transpose; this can be called multiple times to rotate to 0, 90, 180, 270

def unshared_copy(inList):
  '''
  Create a copy of a lists of lists
  '''
  # I use this because of map(list, zip(*img))
  if isinstance(inList, list):
    return list( map(unshared_copy, inList) )
  return inList

# Load image
oldIm = FileImage('/home/USER/Pictures/google doodles/google-doodle-90th-anniversary-of-the-first-demonstration-of-television-6281357497991168.2-hp.jpg')
# Create two empty image (one for +90deg and another for -90deg
newIm90D = EmptyImage(oldIm.height, oldIm.width)
newIm90D_ = EmptyImage(oldIm.height, oldIm.width)

# Create windows for displaying all the images
myWin0D = ImageWin('0Deg', oldIm.width, oldIm.height)
myWin90D = ImageWin('+90Deg', newIm90D.width, newIm90D.height)
myWin90D_ = ImageWin('-90Deg', newIm90D_.width, newIm90D_.height)

# Generate a list of lists from the loaded image
img_to_matrix = []
for row in range(oldIm.getHeight()):
  t = [];
  for column in range(oldIm.getWidth()):
    x = oldIm.getPixel(column, row)
    t.append(x)
  img_to_matrix.append(t)

# Create a copy of the list of lists so that we can demonstrate rotation in both directions
img_to_matrix2 = unshared_copy(img_to_matrix)

# Rotate +90deg
rotate90D(img_to_matrix)
# Rotate -90deg
rotate90D_(img_to_matrix2)

# Load the pixel data in the respective images
for row in range(newIm90D.getHeight()):
  for col in range(newIm90D.getWidth()):
    newIm90D.setPixel(col, row, img_to_matrix[col][row])

for row in range(newIm90D_.getHeight()):
  for col in range(newIm90D_.getWidth()):
    newIm90D_.setPixel(col, row, img_to_matrix2[col][row])

# Display the images
oldIm.draw(myWin0D)
newIm90D.draw(myWin90D)
newIm90D_.draw(myWin90D_)
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Since you named your list of lists `bigLists` I would assume that you want to load huge image. So you should consider modifying my sample code since (as mentioned in the code comments) I do some copying.

**PS:** Frankly, I personally wouldn't bother using an image "library" that can't do basic transformations. I looked inside `cImage.py` and it seems that it uses `PIL`'s `Image` as a basis. `PIL` itself does offer rotation (and other such basic things) out of the box if I recall correctly (I'm more of an OpenCV guy) though I don't know if the `cImage` custom image format is compatible with `PIL`'s image processing tools.

Comment: I actually found out the problem but I still don't know how to solve it. If I'm using any random image, my code works fine, but when using the image saved from cImage it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @voldiemort Again - please don't use the comment area to provide vital pieces of information. Edit your original post.